# Change the color of TabFolder in Eclipse RCP 3.x

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp

I need to change the very bright (almost white) color visible on the attached image and the color of the font on those `TabItems` being a part of white `TabFolder`.
I use CSS and also tried `setBackground` function called on `Composite` and `TabFolder` but without success. The best solution for me would be to change it via CSS if possible

[image]

Comment: You need to provide a lot more info. Is this your code? Are you using the Eclipse 4 style CSS support? Are you sure this is `TabFolder` and not `CTabFolder`?

Comment: Yes, it is my code. Eclipse 4 CSS is supported in my RCP 3.x (I use CSS to color most of the things in my app). Actually I used TabFolder to separate it from CTabFolder and have a chance to color/format it differently in CSS (I already changed it to CTabFolder and CTabItem as I could not set proper visual settings using CSS for TabFolder). The question of this topic is: Does TabFolder/TabItems can be formatted using CSS? How?

Answer (score 3):

There is no specific code for `TabFolder` or `TabItem` in the Eclipse CSS support so they just get the CSS common to all controls such as `background-color` and `color`.

`color` does seem to change the color of the tab folder tab text, `background-color` does **not** change the tab background (it changes the background of the rest of the control).

The Eclipse CSS support works by calling normal SWT methods in the controls, since `TabFolder` does not have methods to set the tab background there is no way this can be done.

`CTabFolder` is much more flexible and allows new tab renderers to be used which can extend the CSS. Also note that on some platforms `CTabFolder` looks substantially different from `TabFolder` (macOS in particular).

You can use CSS classes and ids to restrict your CSS to just your folders. For example in your code use:

```
CSSUtil.setCSSClass(folder, "my-folder-class");
```

to set the CSS class of a folder and in the CSS use the class:

```css
CTabFolder.my-folder-class
{
  swt-tab-renderer: url('bundleclass://org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt/org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.CTabRendering');
  swt-shadow-visible: false;
  swt-simple: false;
  swt-tab-height: 22px;
  swt-unselected-tabs-color:  black;
  swt-selected-tab-fill: black;
  swt-outer-keyline-color: black;
  swt-tab-outline: black;
  swt-shadow-color: black;
  swt-unselected-hot-tab-color-background: #2F2F2F;
  swt-selected-tabs-background: black black 100%;
  color: rgb(128, 128, 128);
}
```

This CSS also shows the use of the standard Eclipse custom tab folder renderer. This is just an example taken from a dark theme for one of my own RCPs.

Comment: Thank You for clarification. Using CSS classes solves my problem